# Error opening a parquet file on Amazon S3 using pyarrow

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I have this code, which is supposed to read a single column data from a parquet file stored on S3:
`fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
data_set = pq.ParquetDataset(f"s3://{bucket}/{key}", filesystem=fs)
column_data = data_set.read(columns=[col_name])`

and I get this excption:
validate_schemas
    self.schema = self.pieces[0].get_metadata(open_file).schema
IndexError: list index out of range

I upgraded to the latest version of pyarrow but it did not help